# Push content of a div to the right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a comment area where users can comment and reply to comments. I want to display a comment and its replies. The problem is that the replies do not align correctly with the parent comment.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bhdk9s28/1/)

**CSS**

```
.alignleft {
    float: left;
}
.alignright {
    float: right;
}
.comment-icon {
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    width: 60px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Current result:

[image].

This's what I want.

[image]

Comment: just a sidenote instead of making your own float classes bootstrap come default with `.pullleft` and `.pullright` that do the same thing

Comment: @NooBskie those don't work well when i'm using them.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the issue... is it happening only on certain browser?

Comment: The default classes in Bootstrap are **.pull-left** and **.pull-right**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well take a look at the updated Fiddle here.
[Updated JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bhdk9s28/2/)

```
<div class="row replies">

                    <div class="col-sm-10 reply-area pull-right">
                        <p class="alignleft">Peter &bull; 2014-12-12</p>
                        <p class="alignright">
                            <span class="badge votes">4</span><a class="comment-vote-up" href="#"><span data-count="1" class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up up"></span></a></span>
            <a class="comment-vote-down" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></span></a></p>
                        <hr style="clear: both">
                        he'd
                    </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2 comment-icon pull-right">
                        <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ultimate-social/150/34_google_plus-512.png" alt="" class="img-circle"  width="60" height="60"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
```